# Running a script at startup via graphical interface doesn't work whereas it works when I run it in cli

Tags: linux, linux-mint, startup

I'm running Linux Mint 20 and try to use the GUI to launch my startups scripts. All are working as expected but two of them:

`xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` AND `mongo-express -a -u XXX -p XXX --url mongodb://localhost:27017/`

When I launch the exact same command in a cli it works correctly. I even tried to click the cog icon `Run now` but it did not work as well. Do I have missed something ?

I tried to search google but didn't found anything about that problem.

Thanks for your help :)

[image]